# Изменить цвет текста в eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, web.xml

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00CIr.jpg)

Подскажите, как изменить цвет на стандартный?

Comment: Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring ?

Answer (score 0):

Хороший подход - установить плагин для тем [Eclipse Color Themes](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/). Там же можно и разные темы повыбирать, и создать свою, и всегда иметь возможность переключиться на любую из них, включая стандартную:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну а детали подправить можно как уже сказано в комментариях, в настройках конкретного редактора.